# Using Instaloader to scan all posts from an account and download (x) most liked

Tags: python, instagram

I "wrote" this code that basically scans all posts from a profile and then downloads the 5 most liked posts.

```
from itertools import islice
from math import ceil

from instaloader import Instaloader, Profile

PROFILE = "profile_name"

L = Instaloader(save_metadata=True, compress_json=False, download_video_thumbnails=False, download_comments=False, post_metadata_txt_pattern="{likes}")

profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, PROFILE)

posts_sorted_by_likes = sorted(profile.get_posts(), key=lambda post: post.likes, reverse=True)

for post in islice(posts_sorted_by_likes, ceil(5)):
    L.download_post(post, PROFILE)
```

1. I would like to know if the code of this script is "clean" since I adapted it from another one.
2. How could I add a list of profiles? Right now I have to write them one by one. I know that it's possible using `profile_list = ['profile1', 'profile2', 'profile3', ...]`but I don't know how to implement it in the code.

Excuse me if the questions are too basic, I'm quite new to Python.

Comment: One of the things that I would say is weird about the code is the use of the `ceil` function - this basically rounds up a floating point (decimal) number to the next integer (so `ceil(2.2) == 3`). However, when it's used in `islice`, `5` by itself is already an integer, so I  don't understand why you need to run `ceil(5)`. You can probably remove the `from math import ceil` line and the function call from `islice`, and use 5 directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to number 2:

If you already know which profiles you want to download from (i.e. you have, as you mention, a `profile_list = ['profile1', 'profile2', 'profile3', ...]`), you can create a list of `Profile` *objects*. You can do this with a `for` loop, or in a more compact way using a list comprehension:

For loop method:

```
profile_objects = []
for p in profile_list:
    profile_objects.append(Profile.from_username(L.context, p))
```

List comprehension:

```
profile_objects = [Profile.from_username(L.context, p) for p in profile_list]
```

After that, you should iterate over the `Profile` object list before iterating over their posts:

```
for profile in profile_objects:
    for post in islice(posts_sorted_by_likes, 5):
        L.download_post(post, PROFILE)
```